# Use a template to handle integers, strings, and arrays of strings

Tags: c++, arrays, string, templates

As the title states, I am trying to use a class template with member functions to handle other functions that use integers, strings, and arrays of user-defined strings from the command line. The file I am working with is:

This file works for functions that are using integers and strings, but not for a function that processes an arbitrary array of user-defined strings from the command line. The error message when I compile for that function is:

What am I doing wrong? As I said before, the work I have in the header file will work for the integers and strings, but it won't work for the array of strings. Any ideas?

Comment: What's unclear about the error message?

Comment: Is it because it is a const? I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: What is the name of the type you are comparing? What is the comparison operation you are doing?

Comment: It looks like `observe` needs to be overloaded with a comparator that can be used when the types do not have an `operator <`.

Comment: Both are of type Data, but `t` is a const. @Barry

Answer (score 1):

`LessThanOnly` defines an `operator<` but not an `operator>`
However `MiniMax` uses both operators.

Either define an `operator>` or switch the logic in `MiniMax::observe` to be :

```
  if (t < min)
      min = t;
  if (max < t)
      max = t;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message explains what the problem is:

```
./minimax.h:65:13: error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const LessThanOnly' and
      'LessThanOnly')
      if (t > max)
          ~ ^ ~~~
```

Here's a hint. What is the name of the types you are trying to compare? What is the operation you are doing to compare them? How do you fix it?

Comment: Both of are type Data, but `t` is a const. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @ComputerScienceUndergrad No, they are not of type `Data` (`Data` isn't even a type). Try again. What type are the operands?